# VERY basic python string

Tags: python, string

I'm very new and just came across an exercise which asks:

> Given a string and a non-negative integer `n`, return a larger string that is `n` copies of the original string.

I answered:

```
def string_times(str, n):
    return(str * n)
```

and passed all tests. The solution provided:

```
def string_times(str, n):
     result = ""
     for i in range(n):  # range(n) is [0, 1, 2, .... n-1]
         result = result + str  # could use += here
     return result
```

My question is: is there any reason why my simpler solution won't work in some cases,
or is it just a matter of a more experienced programmer overthinking things?

Comment: was your answer judged as incorrect? I think the provided solution just have an intention of exposing some knowledge of string concatenation to the user; and it is indeed the purpose of an exercise.

Comment: I much prefer your code; adding up strings by concatenation should generally be avoided, and the single line will be more efficient than an explicit loop. My only issue is with shadowing `str`, but I guess you were provided with the function definition.

Comment: as @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 wrote. The answer uses concepts likes ranges and a `for` loop and is much easier to expand, e.g. other delimiters between the copies. Your solution is clean for the purpose but hides the functionality a bit.

Comment: no my answer was judged correct. I just wrote what made sense to me.

Comment: @tgmath I see, so do you think I should spend some more time working on this because at the moment I would never have thought to write a solution like that.

Comment: @JakeThaHuman I would simply go on. Just try to understand the concept of a loop for the numbers in the range 0 to n-1.

Comment: Probably because this won't help you with a low-level language like `c` at a future time.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus using `str` as a variable name prevents you from accessing the built-in type.

Comment: Basically, if you *understand what the other code is doing* (it's always worth learning from alternative approaches and implementations), don't worry about it. You wrote code that met the spec and passed the tests: good job, that's programming.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct, but the exercise probably wanted to reveal other concepts such as [for loops](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) and string concatenation using `+` and `+=`.

That said, I'd like to add to the stated solution that it is a better practice to use an underscore when you don't really need the loop variable. It's a way of telling future programmers you are not using the variable anywhere in the loop.

It's also better to use [xrange](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) if you don't actually need a list (generated by range). You can try in the interpreter `range(1000000)` and `xrange(1000000)` to see the immediate difference. `xrange` is actually a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), making it a lot more memory efficient.

*in python 3, range returns a generator by default*

```
# changed i to an underscore, using xrange instead of range
for _ in xrange(n):  # xrange(n) *generates* 0, 1, 2 ... n-1
```

Comment: About `range` and `xrange`, I think that your hint applyes only to Python 2.x, in later versions `range` is deleted and `xrange` is renamed to `range`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'll note that in the answer.